# Fetch Output Location from Athena Query Execution Id

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I have query execution id for a certain Athena query. I want to get the Output Location for this query. I know I can fetch the results using query execution id from java aws sdk.
I have created athena client object named 'athenaClient' of class AmazonAthena using my credentials of aws.

```
GetQueryResultsRequest getQueryResultsRequest = new 
GetQueryResultsRequest().withExecutionId(execId);
GetQueryResultsResult getQueryResultsResult = 
athenaClient.getQueryResults(getQueryResultsRequest);
```

Using this getQueryResultsResult, I can fetch the query results.
But I want to get the Output Location through Athena query execution id.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that deep into the Java SDK, but the location of the result can be retrieved through the `getQueryExecution` method.

So it should be something like this:

```
GetQueryExecutionResult result = athenaClient.getQueryExecution(GetQueryExecutionRequest().withExecutionId(execId));
QueryExecution exec = result.getQueryExecution();
ResultConfiguration config = exec.getResultConfiguration();
```

[QueryExecution - AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/athena/model/QueryExecution.html)

[ResultConfiguration - AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/athena/model/ResultConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i create a simple API SDK that you can found on

https://github.com/fulmicotone/aws-java-athena-helper

every improvement is welcome thanks

```
  MyAthena.Builder.standard(ATHENA_DEFAULT_DATABASE,ATHENA_OUTPUT_BUCKET)
 .build()
 .newQuery(ATHENA_SAMPLE_QUERY)
 .submit()
 .waitForQueryToComplete()
 .processResultRows(5, new Consumer<AthenaPageResults>() {
     @Override
     public void accept(AthenaPageResults athenaPageResults) {

         System.out.println("page:"+athenaPageResults.getPage());

     }
 });
```